# How to package firefox built from source code to smaller size?

Tags: firefox, 21.04, source

I recently built firefox form source code, but the folder where mach built firefox is huge!
It's like 12GB in size.

[image]

How Do I make it smaller and portable to carry around on multiple linux machines?
Please Help!

Comment: Firefox-90 : The run time files are ~230MB, which is what you have in the "destination-directory" after doing `make install` ......... https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/firefox

Comment: And for what you want - portability - there's no need to compile. Standalone Firefox that is portable by definition (works in a folder and updates independently of the OS' updates) already exists. TOR Bundle is based on the latest standalone long term support Firewfox version.